# How does the team ensure a good DB design?

Tags: database, database-design

We want to ensure that our team delivers a good performing DB design. But we are not quite sure how to achieve this.

Couple of solutions have been suggested within the team:

- Adding DB indexes to our definition of done. Maybe a rule like: no new/altered queries should use a table scan.
- Maybe we should disable table-scan on our development environment. This way developers are forced to add indexes while developing.
- Or maybe it would be sufficient to monitor for slow queries on a QA environment?

So what is the a good way of achieving a good DB design when you don't have a DBA?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: too bad this question was closed, it's a good one. Good DB design means to design for the actual use case, avoiding/removing redundancies except when warranted for performance reasons (then, manage the redundancy!). To improve for performance first and foremost means to profile (measure) before you act. Then act where the performance lacks. In particular, adding indexes and dealing with table scan behaviour is premature optimisation and generally a defunct practice.

Comment: Having an index for *every* query is not necessarily good DB design. Remember that every additional index slows down inserts and updates, so too many indexes can be counter-productive, especially when the queries they are supposed to speed up are not performance-critical.

Comment: What is a "definition of done"?

Comment: There are lots of books available about how to achieve good DB design. Just google for those and find a team member who is "old school" enough to actually read and learn from books (the latter may be harrder than the first :-)

Comment: Flat out rules are seldom good ones in design.  Each situation needs to be judged on a case by case basis.  There's a cost to doing a table scan.  There's a cost to avoiding a table scan.  It's a trade off.  Design is full of trade offs.

Comment: How about contracting a part-time DBA/someone who knows what they're doing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You fix *"So what is the a good way of achieving a good DB design when you don't have a DBA?"* by getting a DBA.

DB design is not about indexing, that's just part of the overall design.

What columns are in your tables, how to split repeated data into normalised tables and when not to split them for performance reasons; what kind of queries they'll required. All these are DB design topics, indexes, primary and foreign keys, good set of constraints, which ones may be nullable, what kind of datatypes, everything goes in a good DB design and there's no way to answer without a lot of experience.

So get a DBA or start training one of your staff to be a part-time DBA.